# Using @RunAs between a servlet and an EJB

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb

I have the following servlet.

```
@DeclareRoles("remote-guest")
@RunAs("remote-guest")
public class GuestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private Test test;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        test.guest();
    }

}
```

The servlet is mapped such that only users with role `guest` can call it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>guest-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.web.GuestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>guest-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/guest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-role>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>guest-resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/guest</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The `Test` EJB is implemented by the following `TestBean` class.

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles("remote-guest")
public class TestBean implements Test {

    @RolesAllowed("remote-guest")
    public void guest() {
        System.out.println("TestBean.guest()");
    }

}
```

**Problem:** when I call the `GuestServlet` using a user that is mapped only to the `guest` role, the EJB throws an `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException` despite of the presence of the `@RunAs` annotation on the servlet. Should I also map the user to the `remote-guest` role? If the user has to be mapped both to `guest` and `remote-guest`, what's the real purpose of `@RunAs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a user needs to be mapped to the role. Although it might be a different user from the one that has the "guest" role. As stated in the EJB 3.1 specification 17.3.4.1:

> Because the Bean Provider and Application Assembler do not, in
> general, know the security environment of the operational
> environment, the run-as identity is designated by a logical role-name,
> which corresponds to one of the security roles defined by the Bean
> Provider or Application Assembler in the metadata annotations or
> deployment descriptor.
>
> The Deployer then assigns a security principal defined in the
> operational environment to be used as the principal for the run-as
> identity. The security principal assigned by the Deployer should be a
> principal that has been assigned to the security role specified by
> RunAs annotation or by the role-name element of the run-as deployment
> descriptor element.

And oracle jee6 tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnbyr/index.html

The role of @RunAs is to allow communication between 2 containers with different sets of roles and users (as in the link above) or to provide security identity for components that don't have security contexts: for example a Message Driven Bean needs to call another bean that requires the caller to have some roles.